# App Update wiping game data

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play

I'm working on an update of game for a client at the moment and for all intents and purposes it works fine. However it's been reported that 50% of the time, even on the same device, that the save data is being lost and the player has to restart their game. Given the game absorbs several hours of gameplay, this is understandably irritating. I'm however at a loss at what is causing this.

The update required transitioning the game from an Eclipse/ADT solution to the Android Studio/Gradle system in order to accommodate a whole bunch of advert networks/SDKs. This has been done successfully and the app/package signatures etc. don't show any conflicts. The core of the game (written in C++) is unchanged and the Java/JNI wrapper passes the same data to/from the game.

So the problem lies with the update process itself, correct? Or at the very least it's not a code issue as such - a clutch at straws is that maybe it's a newer NDK?  It appears (although I can't confirm) that it forces an uninstall/install of the original app rather than a replacement of the main binary?

**EDIT** The data is stored in internal storage (i.e. private to the app) via `getFilesDir()`. I've not written the original code with regards to actual saving - it simply seems to pack binary data together and streams it out via stdio's `write`. If I launch the game with the same versions it works absolutely fine - it's just the process of updating the app that seems to ruin it.

Comment: You haven't mentioned where or how you save game data.

Comment: Updated my original question with more info, @WLGfx

Comment: According to many answers on SO about app upgrades, it shouldn't delete the apps private data when replacing the APK. Only an uninstall, clear apps data or phone reset would do that. My guess is to look into storing their data online and retrieved when they log in if it is a recurring thing.

Comment: I agree - it _shouldn't_ delete according to many articles. I thought I came across a snippet that there may be conditions due a differing signature/composition of the APK but I would think that would have to be fairly extreme.